# Nodejs: Unable to get query results and store in array

Tags: mysql, node.js

this is my code

```js
const mysqlssh = require('mysql-ssh');
var Promise = require('promise');


const startSSHSQLTunnel = () =>{
    return mysqlssh.connect(
        {
            host: 'xxx.xxx.xx.xxx',
            user: 'ball',
            password: 'r252_bat'
        },
        {
            host: '192.xxx.xxx.xxx',
            user: 'portal',
            password: 'r252_bat',
            database: 'mydb'
        }
    )
}

exports.getSignupSummary = async() => {
    let res = []
    let queryStrings = ['SELECT year, WorkWeek, COUNT(*) AS Count from (SELECT YEAR(signed_up) as year, WEEK(signed_up) as WorkWeek from `chatbots` where signed_up is not null) temp_table group by WorkWeek, year',
    'SELECT year, WorkMonth, COUNT(*) AS Count from (SELECT YEAR(signed_up) as year, MONTH(signed_up) as WorkMonth from `chatbots` where signed_up is not null) temp_table group by WorkMonth, year',
    'SELECT COUNT(*) as count from `chatbots`']
    //SELECT COUNT(*) as count from `chatbots`; 
    getUserData = function(qs, cb) {
        startSSHSQLTunnel().then(client => {
          client.query(qs, 
          function(err, results) { 
            if (err)
              return cb(err);
            cb(undefined, results);
        })});
      }
      
      // Usage:
    queryStrings.map(x => { 
        getUserData(x, 
            function(err, results) {
                res.push(results);
                }
            )
        });

    console.log(res);
}
```

I am trying to get the query results and store in an array called "res"
however I am facing the following issues

1. the results from the callback function can be console.logged but if I store in array and then try to print it out, I see an empty array.
2. I tried to use async -> await but it was no use
3. I tried to encapsulate everything in a new promise and then resolve the results but that was no point as I got an empty promise

please advise

Comment: Seems like an async trouble, i think the array is not populated when you `console.log` it

Comment: I did try to wrap with an await but I got pending promise

Comment: I think you could use the .map function to return an array of promise on `getUserData` and then use `await Promise.all` to resolve those promises

Comment: Can share code?

Comment: Answered below, tell me if it doesn't work, we will debug

Comment: it works like a dream, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try something like this:

```
exports.getSignupSummary = async() => {
  let queryStrings = ['SELECT year, WorkWeek, COUNT(*) AS Count from (SELECT YEAR(signed_up) as year, WEEK(signed_up) as WorkWeek from `chatbots` where signed_up is not null) temp_table group by WorkWeek, year',
  'SELECT year, WorkMonth, COUNT(*) AS Count from (SELECT YEAR(signed_up) as year, MONTH(signed_up) as WorkMonth from `chatbots` where signed_up is not null) temp_table group by WorkMonth, year',
  'SELECT COUNT(*) as count from `chatbots`']
  //SELECT COUNT(*) as count from `chatbots`; 
  getUserData = function(qs, cb) {
    startSSHSQLTunnel().then(client => {
      client.query(qs, function(err, results) { 
        if (err) return cb(err);
        cb(undefined, results);
      });
    });
  }
      
  // Usage:
  const promises = queryStrings.map(x => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      getUserData(x, function(err, results) {
        if (err) reject(err);
        resolve(results);
       });
     });
   });
   const res = await Promise.all(promises);
      
   console.log(res);
}
```

This code uses the `.map` function to create a promise for each of your queries and store it in an array.

Then we use `await Promise.all` to wait for all the promises to be resolved.